# Inversion in affirmative sentences

Tags: usage, inversion, do-support

The Guardian has recently published an interview with Kurt Volker, who stated that:

“We can have a conversation with Ukraine like we would with any other country about **what do they need.**”

[Source](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/aug/31/ukraine-kurt-volker-us-arms-supplies)

Why is he using inversion?

Comment: It's an error -- there should be no inversion: "...about _what they need_". The italicised element is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question). The meaning is “We can have a conversation with Ukraine like we would with any other country about the answer to the question 'What do they need?'"

Comment: This is a transcription of a conversation - so the interviewee may have been speaking stream-of-consciousness or less formally, and thus dropped that 'do' in.  Or perhaps intended that to be an interior quotation - "We can have a conversation ... about 'what do they need?'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sound like something that happens occasionally in conversation. In spoken conversion though, it would come across more naturally.

Think of it like this: “We can have a conversation with Ukraine like we would with any other country about X.” Where X is the question "what do they need?".

In other words, "we can have a conversation with them about the question: what do they need?"